# C# - Pass different types as one Parameter

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

I used Extract Method on this code because there were multiples of this code, and here is what it became:

```
private void InsertStatement(string table, string table2, TestURLGUI4.Form1 form, SQLiteConnection sql_con, ref int dbID, ref int dbID2, Chrome chrome, int max)
{
    try
    {
        List<int> dbIDs = new List<int>();
        using (SQLiteTransaction mytransaction = sql_con.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql_con))
            {
                mycommand.CommandText = "insert or ignore into " + table + " (id, url, title, visit_count, frecency, last_visit_date) values (@dbID,@url,@title,@visit,@frecency,@time)";

                for (var count2 = 0; count2 < chrome.URLs.Count; count2++)
                {
                    URL u = chrome.URLs[count2];
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@dbID", dbID));
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@url", u.url));
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@title", u.title));
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@visit", u.frequency));
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@time", ToPRTime(u.visited)));
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@frecency", ToFrecency(u.frequency)));
                    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dbIDs.Add(dbID);
                    dbID++;
                    form.label1.Text = count2 + "/" + max;
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }

            }
            mytransaction.Commit();
        }
        using (SQLiteTransaction mytransaction = sql_con.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql_con))
            {
                mycommand.CommandText = "insert or ignore into " + table2 + " (id, from_visit, place_id, visit_date, visit_type, session) values (@dbID2,2,@dbID,@time,1, 0)";

                for (var count2 = 0; count2 < chrome.URLs.Count; count2++)
                {
                    URL u = chrome.URLs[count2];
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@dbID2", dbID2));
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@dbID", dbIDs[count2]));
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@time", ToPRTime(u.visited)));
                    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dbID2++;
                    form.label1.Text = count2 + "/" + max;
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }

            }
            mytransaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The only problem is, instead of the Chrome type parameter, I have created multiple instances of different classes, and I need to pass each one, for example, I have

```
IE ie = new IE();
Firefox firefox = new Firefox();
```

etc. Now, how can I modify my parameter so that instead of Chrome, I can pass Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc. all in the same parameter, one at a time?

Comment: The last sentence of your question is confusing to me - do you want to be able to pass any of the browsers in as a single parameter, or *all* of them in as a single parameter?

Comment: And out of interest, do any of these classes inherit from a common base class? Because if so, the former case can be easily solved with polymorphic code.

Comment: Any of them in a single parameter, one at a time. Sorry.

Comment: Well then your choices are: 1) Refactor your code so that all browsers inherit from one Browser class, then change the parameter type to Browser (See mine or Chris's answer) 2) Have each browser implement an interface - I personally think it's more advisable to implement an inheritance hierarchy (See Tieson's, Doug's, or Saeed's answer) or 3) Overload the method, which will just lead to insane code duplication. Not advisable.

Comment: Thanks, but for number one, is there a way I can do this without replacing all of my new instances with `Browser.IE ie = new Browser.IE();`?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question - if you were to derive IE from a class called Browser, you could still write `IE ie = new IE()`. I'll edit my answer to supply more information about inheritance.

Comment: Well, I get an error that IE is not found, and I have to type out Browser.IE instead.

Comment: Can you edit your question to supply the code?

Comment: The code you supplied is not inheritance. See mine or Chris's answer for an explanation of how to properly implement the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your types are browsers, which means that you can (and should) refactor your code so that they all derive from one shared Browser class, if it's not already like this. Once you do this, you can polymorphically change your method:

```
private void InsertStatement(string table, string table2, TestURLGUI4.Form1 form, SQLiteConnection sql_con, ref int dbID, ref int dbID2, Browser browser, int max)
```

If you are unwilling to do this then the only other solution I can think of is overloading the method.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) supplies information about inheritance in C#. Basically, what you do is:

```
class Browser
{
}

class IE : Browser
{
}
```

You can then still initialize IE like this:

```
IE ie = new IE();
```

But you can also initialize it polymorphically like this:

```
 Browser ie = new IE();
```

If you derive more classes from Browser, such as Firefox, Chrome, etc. then you can treat them all as a single type, Browser, inside a method.

Answer (score 2):

Have the different browsers inherit from a base `Browser` class (or implement a common interface) and pass that in.

```
public abstract class Browser
{
    public List<URL> URL { get; private set; }

    protected Browser
    {
        URL = new List<URL>();
    }

    public abstract void NavigateTo(URL url);
}
```

Then implement the browsers and their specific functionality as needed:

```
public class InternetExplorer : Browser
{
    private Random rand = new Random();
    public override void NavigateTo(URL url)
    {
        if (rand.NextDouble() < 0.5)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        else
            url.Navigate();
    }   
}

public class Firefox : Browser
{
    public override void NavigateTo(URL url)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        url.Navigate();
    }
}

public class Chrome : Browser
{
    public override void NavigateTo(URL url)
    {
        url.Navigate();
        GoFaster();
    }
}
```

Rewrite your method to take the `Browser` and promote whatever shared properties are necessary to that base class:

`private void InsertStatement(string table, string table2, TestURLGUI4.Form1 form, SQLiteConnection sql_con, ref int dbID, ref int dbID2, Browser browser, int max)`

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to create a common interface type that the browser classes can implement (something like `IBrowser`). Then your method signature becomes:

```
private void InsertStatement(string table, string table2, TestURLGUI4.Form1 form, SQLiteConnection sql_con, ref int dbID, ref int dbID2, IBrowser browser, int max)
```

And within the method you'll have to add some conditional logic to figure out which type it is:

```
if(browser is Firefox)
{
...
}
```

Of course, if the browser types all do the same thing, you should probably just have one `Browser` class that has some sort of `UserAgent` field to identify it. Then you really don't need the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Have them all implement an interface:

```
interface Browser
{

}

class Firefox : Browser
{

}
class IE : Browser
{

}

Browser ie = new IE();
//...
public void someMethod(Browser b)
//...
```